# How can I input the correct encoding to pbcopy in node.js?

Tags: node.js, pbcopy

```
const proc = require('child_process').spawn('pbcopy');
const iconv = require('iconv-lite');
const name = '吉星高照';

function iconvDecode(str = '') {
  return iconv.decode(Buffer.from(str, 'binary'), 'cp936');
}

function pbcopy(data) {
  proc.stdin.write(iconvDecode(data));
  proc.stdin.end();
  return data;
}

pbcopy(name);
```

The expected output from the clipboard (on macOS) should be `吉星高照` but instead it is   `Ë±®`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I need to set the environment variable `LC_CTYPE` for pbcopy:

```
const proc = require('child_process').spawn('pbcopy', {
  env: {
    LC_CTYPE: 'UTF-8',
  },
});
const name = '吉星高照';

function pbcopy(data) {
  proc.stdin.write(data);
  proc.stdin.end();
  return data;
}

pbcopy(name);
```